# RethinkDB - get range of values inside nested arrays

Tags: rethinkdb

I am new to RethinkDB, and am working with a data set with rows like the below:

```
{
    "data": {
        "items": [
           {
               "name: "Foo",
               "value": 20
           },
           {
               "name: "Bar",
               "value": 70
           }
        ]
    }
}
```

I would like to run a query to return the range of item values in the entire dataset, for which the name is "Foo".

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could write `[row('data')('items')('value').min(), row('data')('items')('value').max()]`.

Comment: wouldn't this then include all items? I would like to get the range for items that have the name "Foo".

Comment: You could write `row('data')('items').filter({name: "FOO"})('value')` for that.